# TextView take extra space

Tags: android, textview

One of my TextView is `taking extra space` even though there isn't any padding or margin attached with it. As you see in below picture

[image]

TextView xml code

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txt_bundle_change_percentage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:alpha="0.6"
    android:fontFamily="@font/suisse_intl_semi_bold"
    android:text="14.92%"
    android:textColor="@color/bundleScreenTextColor"
    android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />
```

layout xml file which contains the TextView

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bundle_change_percentage_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bundle_change_percentage_value_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/txt_bundle_change_percentage_icon_up"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_9sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:alpha="0.6"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_value_up"
            android:tint="@color/bundleScreenTextColor"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/txt_bundle_change_percentage_icon_down"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_9sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_8sdp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:alpha="0.6"
            android:scaleY="-1"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_value_up"
            android:tint="@color/bundleScreenTextColor"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_bundle_change_percentage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:alpha="0.6"
            android:fontFamily="@font/suisse_intl_semi_bold"
            android:text="14.92%"
            android:textColor="@color/bundleScreenTextColor"
            android:textSize="@dimen/_12ssp" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_bundle_change_percentage_heading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.6"
        android:fontFamily="@font/suisse_intl_regular"
        android:text="@string/txt_24h_price_change"
        android:textColor="@color/bundleScreenTextColor"
        android:textSize="@dimen/_9ssp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: your font might be the issue. Try with the default font

Comment: simply use android:padding="0dp" to remove default padding in textview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setIncludeFontPadding (boolean includepad)
```

or in XML this would be:

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

Comment: thanks! it worked, but still getting some space. Can you think of any other solution aswell?

Comment: have u used custom font ?

Answer (score 0):

when u need closer add this to align text to the top

```
   textView.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please update this code. it will work.

```
<TextView
android:id="@+id/txt_bundle_change_percentage"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:height="24dp"
android:alpha="0.6"
android:text="14.92%"
android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
android:textSize="24sp"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
android:includeFontPadding="false"
android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="-2dp"
/>
```